# Signing out using Firebase and Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
mlogbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    }
}
```

I am trying to follow the official documentation of Firebase and trying to sign out an already signed in user.

I have made a button and set an `onClickListener` which calls the signout function. But, the problem is that the button simply does nothing when clicked.

Is there an alternative method to achieve the same or have I left out some required code?

Comment: Please add some code of your button inside the layout and where did you set the `onClickListener`?

Comment: If the button doesn't respond to clicks, the problem is in how you attach the listener. Please edit your questions to include the minimal, but complete code that finds the view and attache the listener.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your OnClickListener works and FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut() is called you should have an FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener attached to the Activity:

```
private boolean isAuthListenerSet = false;

private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            //User is signed in
        } else {
            //User is signed out - insert your logic here
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!isAuthListenerSet) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        isAuthListenerSet = true;
    }
}

 @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        isAuthListenerSet = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the logout :
When you login using the auth functionality, Then it store auth token in local storage on your device.

So you can logout using `refreance.unauth();`

May be it's work for you,

Comment: `unauth()` is the sign-out method for the Firebase 2.x SDK. OP is using the newer Firebase 3.x/9.x.